# How to run weka classifier in java / JSP without reading ARFF file?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, classification, weka

I want to apply weka classifiers library on my java file, but commonly this library only reads csv and arff files.

Is there any other way to use the classifier directly ?
like using stringbuffer or arraylist or anything ?

Thanks !
please help me

Comment: You can create an Instances object by hand and pass it to the classifier. https://weka.wikispaces.com/Programmatic+Use